# TO_DATE format SQL

Tags: sql, string, date, variables, ora-01830

I'm beginner. I have a problem that I can't solved. I would like to add the arguments for DATE. But I have an exception: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.
My code is below.

```
AND 
TO_DATE(so.org_due_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') >= ('01-11-2021')
```

Can somebody give tips how can I add this arguments? Thanks every1 for help.
I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `org_due_date` column be *text*, containing text dates in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`, the comparison should be:

```sql
TO_DATE(so.org_due_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') >= date '2021-11-01';
```

While the input to the `TO_DATE()` function is text in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`, one valid Oracle date literal takes the format given above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `so.org_due_date` is a `DATE` datatype, the `TO_DATE` function should be used on the right side.

```
AND so.org_due_date >= TO_DATE('01-11-2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Or use a date literal in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
AND so.org_due_date >= DATE'2021-11-01'
```